# Notation for a particular tensor field

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, tensors

Suppose that $E$ is a bundle with metric $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ over a manifold $M$ and consider an $E$-valued $1$-form $A \in \Gamma(T^*M \otimes E)$. We can write $A$ in coordinates as
$$ A = dx^i \otimes A_i. $$
Is there some standard coordinate-free notation for the tensor field defined by
$$ \langle A_i, A_j \rangle \, dx^i \otimes dx^j ? $$
If $A$ is simply a normal $1$-form (i.e. if $E$ is just $\mathbb R$ interpreted as a trivial bundle), then we could denote this as
$$ A \otimes A = A_iA_j \, dx^i \otimes dx^j, $$
but I can't come up with a good notation for the general case, so I wanted to check if such a notation already exists.

Comment: Is $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ really a metric? Isn't it an inner product?

Comment: @md2perpe What do you mean? Here, when I say metric I meant it in the sense of (semi-)Riemannian geometry (i.e. a metric is a smoothly varying inner product on the fibers of a bundle), rather than a metric in the sense of topology (i.e. a distance function). But I thought this was understood from the context.

Comment: Okay. I only have a shallow knowledge of bundle theory and its terminology so I didn't know that. Probably it's time to get some deeper knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't seen this specific operation before, there's a similar situation in Lie algebra valued differential forms: given a manifold $M$, a Lie algrabra $\mathfrak{g}$ with basis $v_1,\cdots,v_m$, and two $\mathfrak{g}$ valued forms
$$
\omega=v_i\otimes\omega^i\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \eta=v_i\otimes\eta^i \\
\omega^i\in\Omega^kM\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \eta^i\in\Omega^lM
$$
Authors will often write the Lie bracket of forms in one of two ways:
$$
[\omega,\eta]=[\omega\wedge\eta]:=[v_i,v_j]\otimes(\omega^i\wedge\eta^j)
$$
In analogy with the second, it might make sense to write
$$
\langle A\otimes B\rangle:=\langle A_i,B_j\rangle dx^i\otimes dx^j
$$
Where $A=A_i\otimes dx^i$ and $B=B_i\otimes dx^i$ are $E$-valued $1$-forms. This seems difficult to misinterpret, since $A\otimes B\in\Gamma(T^0_2TM\otimes_MT^2_0E)$ is a well defined tensor field, and there is only one way to contract it with the inner product (unless $TM$ also has a Riemannian metric).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will consider this notation. In my case $TM$ does come with a Riemannian metric, but confusion could be avoided by specifying that the brackets refer to the $E$-inner product,e.g.  by writing something like $ \langle A \otimes B \rangle^E. $

Comment: @MSDG: Another reasonable option is to write $\operatorname{tr}_{E}(A \otimes B)$. Here, $A \otimes B$ is a section of $T^{*}M \otimes E \otimes T^{*}M \otimes E$ so it is clear you are contracting the $E$ part using the (bundle) metric.

Comment: @levap Thank you. I will consider this one as well.